# Poorly Worded JavaScript Lexical Scope Example

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm reading an article to try to understand lexical scope and how *VariableEnvironment* works. I understand the code and it makes sense but I don't get the preceding explanation and that worries me a bit. Could someone re-word it for me to make sure I'm completely understanding this?

> Every function gets a [[scope]] property, and when the function is invoked the value of the scope property is assigned to the *outer lexical environment reference* (or *outerLex*) property of its VariableEnvironment. (ES 5 10.4.3.5-7) In this way, each VariableEnvironment inherits from the VariableEnvironment of its lexical parent. This scope chaining runs the length of the lexical hierarchy starting from the global object.

```
//VariableEnvironment: {x: undefined, etc.};
var x = "global";
//VariableEnvironment: {x: "global", etc.};

function outer() {
    //VariableEnvironment: {y: undefined, outerLex: {x: "global", etc.}};
    var y = "outer";    
    //VariableEnvironment: {y: "outer", outerLex: {x: "global", etc.}};

    function inner() {
        //VariableEnvironment: {x: undefined, outerLex: {y: "outer", outerLex: {x:"global", etc.}};
        var x = "inner";    
        //VariableEnvironment: {x: "inner", outerLex: {y: "outer", outerLex: {x:"global", etc.}};
    }
}
```

Is there also a way to access the VariableEnvironment of a function? *function*.VariableEnvironment? Or *function*.[[scope]]? Neither seem to work.

---

**Update**

The article in question is [here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/understanding-javascript-closures/)

Comment: No, there is no way to explicitly obtain a reference to the scope "object". Code has access to it implicitly by the rules of symbol resolution. There's is no equivalent of `this`, `window`, `global`, or anything else like that to mean, "the place(s) where variable references are resolved".

Comment: Please link the article you're reading, or cite it appropriately if it's not online.

Comment: Can you try to re-word it yourself, so that we can check whether you understood it correctly?

Comment: @Bergi I've attached the link to the article

Comment: @Bergi to me, it should read something like "The _outerLex_ property is assigned to the `VariableEnvironment` object which is referenced by the `[[scope]]` property." How they word it seems backwards to me.

Comment: @inthenameofmusik: I don't think they got it backwards, but it's maybe a bit ambigous. The VariableEnvironment that is referenced by the [[scope]] property of the closure is assigned as the outerLex property of the VariableEnvironment that is created in the call.

Comment: @Bergi ahh I think I'm getting closer. So as soon as the function is invoked, the [[scope]] property is _not_ inclusive of the coming variables that will be declared inside the function. It's only a representation of the outer lexical scopes, which will be placed into the VariableEnvironment as `outerLex`. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @inthenameofmusik: Yes, exactly, the [[scope]] property is how the function remembers its lexical closure scope.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you. Just to be clear: let's say we were in the `inner` function. Technically speaking, it would **not** be correct to say that `var x = 'inner';` is in the function's lexical scope, because the lexical scope is the _surrounding_ variables of the closure. Correct? It would be more proper to say that `var x = 'inner';` is in the function's Variable Environment?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is what that word *lexical* means in this context. The "lexical" scope is the scope that can be seen plainly by looking at the function in the context of its definition in the source code, at the  declarations within the function (`var`, `let`, `const`, `function`), and at the declarations in the layers of enclosing functions outward to the global scope. It's a process of just finding the curly braces and surrounding `function` declarations or expressions.

That description, then, is just a formal way of saying that symbol references are resolved by looking for symbols defined in the local scope, and then in each of the succession of surrounding "more global" scopes, all the way out to the actual global scope. (Note that in Node, things are a little different, because the actual global scope is not directly part of the lexical scope chain.)

I've seen "lexical scoping" also referred to as "static scoping", I think, which makes sense as it implies that the scope rules are finalized at the point of creation for each function (and, in ES2015, each block, for `let`). In particular, scoping is not *dynamic* — there's nothing involved in the rules about where or when a function is *invoked*.

Comment: Oh, and formal parameters also count as symbols defined in a scope.

Answer (score 1):

This question largely relates, or rather is in fact a question about closures, as it is written in the article you linked, there is a really well written aticle about this, which helped me understand a lot, here it is:

[About javascript closures](http://web.archive.org/web/20080209105120/http:/blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies)